# Constructing a decreasing sequence that converges to $0$ in probability given convergence in probability to $0$

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose that for some sequence of positive random variables $N^r$ we have for any $\epsilon>0$, $P(N^r \ge \epsilon)\to 0$ as $r \to \infty$.

How can we construct a sequence $\epsilon_r \downarrow 0$ such that $P(N^r \ge \epsilon_r)\to 0$? The difficulty I have here is finding a decreasing sequence to $0$ in $r$ such that $\{N^r \ge \epsilon_r\}$ tends to zero simultaneously as $r \to \infty$. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could show me the trick in constructing such a sequence.

Comment: I'd start by showing there is an $r_0$ depending on $\epsilon > 0$ such that $r \geq r_0$ implies $P(N^r \geq \epsilon) \leq \epsilon$.  Then choose any decreasing sequence that converges to $0$ you want and extract a sequence of corresponding $r_0$s.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I can find inductively $R_i$ and $\epsilon_i$ such that we have $P(N^r\ge \epsilon_i)\le 2^{-R_i}$ for all $r\ge \R_i$, but here we need to find a uniform $r$, that is an $\epsilon_r \downarrow 0$ that gives $P(N^r \ge \epsilon_r)\to 0$ for all $r$. This is the part that I am struggling to find.

Comment: If you already have an increasing sequence $R_i$ corresponding to a decreasing sequence $a_i$ (which you've written as $\epsilon_i$ but we need to distinguish it from the final sequence, so we should choose another letter), then just define $\epsilon_r = a_i$ where $R_i \leq r < R_{i+1}$.